# Іти за водою чи по воду?

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно сформулювати фразу: *іти за водою* чи *іти по воду* (у значенні піти принести води)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сайт «Мова — ДНК нації» [пропонує](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/hoditi-za-gribami-chi-po-gribi) таку інфографіку, яка також може слугувати мнемонікою:

[image: "за хлібом" чи "по хліб"]

Мовознавець Борис Антоненко-Давидович (цитата з того ж ресурсу):

> У декого часом виникає питання: як правильно сказати по-українському: *пішов по воду* чи *пішов за водою*? Це залежить від того поняття, яке ми вкладаємо в речення:
>
> Якщо йдеться про **мету руху**, то треба ставити прийменник ПО:
>
> - *«Ми ходили **по гриби**»* – П. Воронько
>
> Якщо **напрям руху** – прийменник ЗА
>
> - *«Пливи, косо, тихо **за водою**, а я піду слідом **за тобою**»* – Народна пісня;
> - *«Я йду **по лікаря**, бо хворому дуже тяжко»*, але *«Я пішов **за лікарем** до його кабінету взяти рецепт»*.