# "Нахилятися за" чи "нахилятися по"?

Tags: прийменники

Яке речення є граматично правильним?

> Катерина нахилилася **за** квіткою.
>
> Катерина нахилилася **по** квітку.

Я маю на увазі те, що Катерина нахилася щоб зіравати її.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Іти за водою чи по воду?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2889/%d0%86%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%8e-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83)

Answer (score 3):

Літературне слововживання

> ***[ПО](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31842.html)*** прийм. Вж. у словосп.: по березень, по закону (і за законом), по
>   заслузі, по змозі, по карбованцю за кілограм, по коліна (і до колін) у
>   воді, по пошті (і поштою), по праву руку, по радіо передавати, по
>   суботах, по телефону (і телефоном), іти по воду (і рідше за водою),
>   іти по гриби (і за грибами), іти за компасом, кампанія по виборах,
>   наказ по армії, товариш по зброї, черговий по школі.
>
> ***[За](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53399/30820.html)*** прийм. Вж. у словосп.: взятися за зброю (і до зброї), взятися
>   за роботу (і до роботи), за власним бажанням (і з власного бажання),
>   за всякої погоди, за два кроки від мене, за допомогою (і з допомогою),
>   за дорученням, за законом, за звичаєм, за зразком, за ініціативою (і з
>   ініціативи), за наказом (і з наказу), за повідомленням, за прикладом,
>   за пропозицією, за теперішніх часів, за умови, йти за грибами (також
>   по гриби), іти за компасом (і по компасу), пливти за течією, сідати за
>   стіл (і до столу), старший за віком, туга за батьківщиною, українець
>   за походженням (і з походження), вітер – 15 метрів за секунду.

"[Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/pryjmennyky#po-za-z-na)" Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича

> Прийменником по користуються на позначення місця руху: «Він тинявся
>   без діла по вулицях і майданах столиці»; «Мені багато доводилось
>   їздити по містах і селах України». Але неправильно кажуть: «Я живу по
>   вулиці Леніна», — замість: «Я живу на вулиці Леніна»......Все залежить
>   від того поняття, яке ми вкладаємо в речення: якщо йдеться про мету
>   руху, то треба ставити прийменник по («Ми ходили по гриби». — П.
>   Воронько), якщо напрям руху — прийменник за («Пливи, косо, тихо за
>   водою, а я піду слідом за тобою». —

Тобто, ***Катерина нахилилася по квітку.***